# error inflating class fragment android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hi i've this problem with google maps v2 api, i follow many tutorials (also official tutorial) and also i've seen many fix to this error but they don't work.
i've this logcat error if i run application on my device(acer e330):

```
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mappa2/com.example.mappa2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.example.mappa2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     ... 11 more
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at maps.aj.ay.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at maps.aj.ay.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at maps.aj.al.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at maps.aj.bf.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at maps.aj.be.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at bcw.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb$4.b(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.a(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-23 21:11:08.391: E/AndroidRuntime(9419):     ... 21 more
```

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.mappa2;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    public LatLng casa=new LatLng(42.93289301245662,13.085575103759766);
    public LatLng piazza=new LatLng(42.931344,13.087301);   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        crea();
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void crea(){
        if(map==null){
            map=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            Marker c=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(casa).title("Casa"));
            Marker d=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(piazza).title("Piazza"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(casa, 15));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10),2000,null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mappa2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
            android:name="com.example.mappa2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mappa2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mappa2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBgYv8RmGt2xuHR3LL9JaNQVulvEW2C3P0" /> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: com.google.android.maps.API_KEY -> com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read your log more carefully!

```
API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

I cannot explain this line more clearly ;-)

`"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` is different than `"com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"`

;-)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key) for the Maps API Key